# How to implement search on column of varchar type

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `tblJobs` on which I want to implement search on a column `JobDescription`. I

I have more than 70,000 rows in this table. I successfully implemented this, but the way I used is too slow.

Can anyone pls help me to sort out this problem? The SQL stored procedure I am using is this:

```
    Create Procedure Sp_SearchJobs
     (
        @SearchValue varchar(Max)
     )
    AS
BEGIN
    WITH SplitTblJobs AS
    (
        SELECT tbljobs.*, s.ListValue FROM tbljobs tbljobs
        CROSS APPLY  dbo.FN_ListToTable(' ',tbljobs.JobDescription) AS s
    )

    , WordMatchCount AS 
              (
      SELECT s.JobID,COUNT(*) AS CountOfWordMatch FROM                         dbo.FN_ListToTable('',@SearchValue) v
      INNER JOIN SplitTblJobs s ON v.ListValue=s.ListValue
      GROUP BY s.JobID
      HAVING COUNT(*)>0
               )
    , SearchLen AS 
    (
      SELECT n.Number,SUBSTRING(@SearchValue,1,n.Number) AS PartialSearchValue
      FROM Numbers n WHERE n.Number<=LEN(@SearchValue)
            )
     , MatchLen AS 
    (
      SELECT tbljobs.JobID,MAX(l.Number) MatchStartLen FROM tbljobs tbljobs
      LEFT OUTER JOIN SearchLen l ON LEFT(tbljobs.JobDescription,l.Number)=l.PartialSearchValue
      GROUP BY tbljobs.JobID
    )
      SELECT  tbljobs.*,w.CountOfWordMatch,m.MatchStartLen FROM tbljobs tbljobs
      LEFT OUTER JOIN WordMatchCount  w ON tbljobs.JobID=w.JobID
      LEFT OUTER JOIN MatchLen        m ON tbljobs.JobID=m.JobID
      WHERE w.CountOfWordMatch>0
      ORDER BY w.CountOfWordMatch DESC,m.MatchStartLen DESC,LEN(tbljobs.JobDescription) 
      DESC,tbljobs.JobDescription ASC
END
```

Here in the function there is a function used. The code for that table-valued function is this:

```
  Create FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_ListToTable]
  (
       @SplitOn  char(1)    
      ,@List   varchar(8000)
  )
  RETURNS TABLE

  AS  RETURN 
  (

    SELECT
      ListValue
    FROM (SELECT
              LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(List2, number+1, CHARINDEX(@SplitOn, List2, number+1)-number - 1))) AS ListValue
              FROM (
                       SELECT @SplitOn + @List + @SplitOn AS List2
                   ) AS dt
                  INNER JOIN dbo.Numbers n ON n.Number < LEN(dt.List2)
              WHERE SUBSTRING(List2, number, 1) = @SplitOn
         ) dt2
    WHERE ListValue IS NOT NULL AND ListValue!='');
```

There is another table used here . The structure of that is as follows:

```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Numbers]
   (
     [Number] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
         CONSTRAINT [PK_Numbers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
         (
           [Number] ASC
         )
         WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) 
        ON [PRIMARY]
   ) ON [PRIMARY]

   GO
```

To make this procedure to run ..

1. Make table described above
2. Make function
3. Make stored procedure.

I want to implement search on decscription column of `tbljobs`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you using SQL Server you should enable and use the full-text search.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx

Comment: No my full text search is not enabled...It is greyed out. I m using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM)  Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition on Windows NT 5.2 <X86> (Build 3790: Service Pack 2) (Hypervisor)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to reinvent the wheel here - if all you want is a simple substring search, use the LIKE operator.

If you need more advanced search features, check the documentation of your RDBMS (I assume SQL server) on how to perform fulltext searches.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer Frank..!!  I m trying tom integrate full text search ... I have followed every steps given on various websites..but nothing helps me out..My Full Text-Index option dont gets enabled..Pls help me out ...Thanx in advance